# Санитарный и гигиенический: синонимы или нет?

Tags: синонимы

Подскажите, пожалуйста: слова "санитарный" и "гигиенический" являются синонимами или нет? Например, "санитарное (гигиеническое) состояние" или "санитарные (гигиенические) требования".
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слова "санитарный и гигиенический" имеют непосредственное отношение к здоровью человека, о чем свидетельствует и их происхождение: ГИГИЕНА- от греч. hygieinos - здоровый, САНИТАРИЯ - от лат. sanitas - здоровье. Тем не менее, их значения различаются: с гигиеной мы, в первую очередь, связываем здоровый  образ жизни, а санитария - это  меры по его обеспечению.

В сочетаниях  с такими словами, как  "состояние, требования", мы можем использовать оба прилагательных (здесь области их значений частично совпадают), в других же случаях это сделать невозможно - например, существуют только гигиенические навыки, обеспечивающие здоровье,  и только санитарная обработка помещения в качестве необходимой меры по предотвращению заболеваний.

Также обратим внимание на существование выражений "санитарно-гигиенические и санитарно-эпидемиологические требования", то есть санитарные требования по гигиене и санитарные требования по эпидемиологии.  Это также доказывает, что области значений слов "санитарный и гигиенический" различны, синонимами они в большинстве случаев не являются.